# Can i execute curl command using ajax/javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl, google-cloud-messaging

Here is my curl command is there anyway to execute this command using ajax/javascript/jquery anyone of them.m passing Authorization key,Content-Type,endpoint in curl command to send push notifications

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSyD9d_MQZF1y_hPm-xUdgnM25Ny4" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"dWvRQjY01Uw:APA91bESY0_Zl-WBY9mXH3x8_Ul0eZgvncvSX_hf0chY1RmHJqumzHiHAdGmSE7SOvjirP9tOoJbceLUtXbKLMRkRbWHcjAWEU68CysLv4_Cui6uHGIIW8Hvnpd4OFNbfto-HV1\"]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if that site allows [cross-origin requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) from your origin; if it doesn't, you'll be blocked by the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

In jQuery it would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "key=AIzaSyD9d_MQZF1y_hPm-xUdgnM25Ny4",
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "registration_ids": [
            "dWvRQjY01Uw:APA91bESY0_Zl-WBY9mXH3x8_Ul0eZgvncvSX_hf0chY1RmHJqumzHiHAdGmSE7SOvjirP9tOoJbceLUtXbKLMRkRbWHcjAWEU68CysLv4_Cui6uHGIIW8Hvnpd4OFNbfto-HV1"
        ]
    })
})
.done(function() {
    // Success
})
.fail(function() {
    // Error
});
```

Details [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

But if that site *doesn't* support cross-origin resource sharing with your origin, then you'll have to use a server to make the request.

Comment: hello @T.J Crowder after executing this code i got error cross-origin  ------->                   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send?{%22registration_ids%22:[%22dWvRQjY…OvjirP9tOoJbceLUtXbKLMRkRbWHcjAWEU68CysLv4_Cui6uHGIIW8Hvnpd4OFNbfto-HV1%22]}. The request was redirected to 'https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.   How can i resolve it?

Comment: @RC: Well, as I said above, the other site has to allow cross-origin access. If it doesn't, you'll need to do the request from a server, not a browser.

Comment: @RC: If you mean help you do the request from a server, you already are: Using `curl`. Otherwise, you have to use whatever features of the server-side programming environment you're using are. You haven't mentioned one, so it's kind of hard to help you. Do your research, make an attempt, and if you get stuck post a question. The question you asked ("How do I do this with ajax") has been answered.

Comment: @TJ Crowder : m working on push notifications in progressive web apps and i want to make request to gcm to send notifications via XHR

Comment: @RC: For at least the third time: You can't, if the server doesn't support cross-origin resource sharing with your origin, which apparently it doesn't. XHR is governed by the SOP. You can't get around the SOP without cooperation from the server at the other end.